# Search as you type functionality in amazon CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch

How should I go about implementing search as you type in amazon CloudSearch to search Amazon dynamodb. Like the way algolia does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search-as-you-type by using a prefix search every time the user enters a character -- it would look something like this:

```
(prefix field=name 'dri')
```

The prefix search is necessary because a regular search for `q=dri` would not match `drive`, `drivel`, etc.

Here are the prefix search docs:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html#searching-text-prefixes

If you don't want to specify the fields for your prefix search you can use a query of the form `q=dri* | dri` (the non-* term is necessary because `q=dri*` does not match the word "dri" -- it requires there to be at least one additional character).

Comment: What I really want is search as you type functionality something that algolia provides not just suggestions alone. Like Google instant search.